# WCF serialization problems in combination with LINQ to SQL single-table inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, linq-to-sql

In a project I'm using LINQ to SQL and WCF.

I have the following single-table inheritance:

[image: Single-table inheritance]

When I call a WCF method (`GetMediaForItem`) which return's a list of `ItemMedia` (the base type) objects, I get the exception `A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`.

But when I call a WCF method (`GetYouTubeVideosForItem`) which returns a list of `YouTubeVideo`'s (one of the derived types), it works fine.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MediaService : IMediaService
{
    ...

    // this throws a System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
    public List<ItemMedia> GetMediaForItem(int itemId)
    {
        using (var context = _db.CreateContext())
        {
            context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

            return (from i in context.ItemMedias
                    where i.ItemID == itemId
                    orderby i.Order
                    select i).ToList();
        }
    }

    // this works fine
    public List<YouTubeVideo> GetYouTubeVideosForItem(int itemId)
    {
        using (var context = _db.CreateContext())
        {
            context.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

            return (from i in context.ItemMedias.OfType<YouTubeVideo>()
                    where i.ItemID == itemId
                    orderby i.Order
                    select i).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMediaService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "Media?itemId={itemId}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
    )]
    List<ItemMedia> GetMediaForItem(int itemId);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "YouTubeVideos?itemId={itemId}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
    )]
    List<YouTubeVideo> GetYouTubeVideosForItem(int itemId);
}
```

And here are the generated models:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.ItemMedia")]
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.InheritanceMappingAttribute(Code="media", Type=typeof(ItemMedia), IsDefault=true)]
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.InheritanceMappingAttribute(Code="video", Type=typeof(YouTubeVideo))]
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.InheritanceMappingAttribute(Code="image", Type=typeof(Image))]
public partial class ItemMedia : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _ID;

    private int _ItemID;

    private string _MediaType;

    private int _Order;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _AddedOn;

    private System.Nullable<int> _AddedBy;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _ChangedOn;

    private System.Nullable<int> _ChangedBy;

    private EntityRef<Item> _Item;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnIDChanging(int value);
partial void OnIDChanged();
partial void OnItemIDChanging(int value);
partial void OnItemIDChanged();
partial void OnMediaTypeChanging(string value);
partial void OnMediaTypeChanged();
partial void OnOrderChanging(int value);
partial void OnOrderChanged();
partial void OnAddedOnChanging(System.Nullable<System.DateTime> value);
partial void OnAddedOnChanged();
partial void OnAddedByChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnAddedByChanged();
partial void OnChangedOnChanging(System.Nullable<System.DateTime> value);
partial void OnChangedOnChanged();
partial void OnChangedByChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
partial void OnChangedByChanged();
#endregion

    public ItemMedia()
    {
        this._Item = default(EntityRef<Item>);
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ID != value))
            {
                this.OnIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ID");
                this.OnIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ItemID", DbType="Int")]
    public int ItemID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ItemID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ItemID != value))
            {
                if (this._Item.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                {
                    throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                }
                this.OnItemIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ItemID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ItemID");
                this.OnItemIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_MediaType", DbType="VarChar(10)", IsDiscriminator=true)]
    public string MediaType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._MediaType;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._MediaType != value))
            {
                this.OnMediaTypeChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._MediaType = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("MediaType");
                this.OnMediaTypeChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="[Order]", Storage="_Order", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int Order
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Order;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Order != value))
            {
                this.OnOrderChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Order = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Order");
                this.OnOrderChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_AddedOn", DbType="DateTime")]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> AddedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return this._AddedOn;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._AddedOn != value))
            {
                this.OnAddedOnChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._AddedOn = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("AddedOn");
                this.OnAddedOnChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_AddedBy", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> AddedBy
    {
        get
        {
            return this._AddedBy;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._AddedBy != value))
            {
                this.OnAddedByChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._AddedBy = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("AddedBy");
                this.OnAddedByChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ChangedOn", DbType="DateTime")]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> ChangedOn
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ChangedOn;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ChangedOn != value))
            {
                this.OnChangedOnChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ChangedOn = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ChangedOn");
                this.OnChangedOnChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ChangedBy", DbType="Int")]
    public System.Nullable<int> ChangedBy
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ChangedBy;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ChangedBy != value))
            {
                this.OnChangedByChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ChangedBy = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ChangedBy");
                this.OnChangedByChanged();
            }
        }
    }
            [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Item_ItemMedia", Storage="_Item", ThisKey="ItemID", OtherKey="ID", IsForeignKey=true)]
    public Item Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Item.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            Item previousValue = this._Item.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) 
                        || (this._Item.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._Item.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.ItemMedias.Remove(this);
                }
                this._Item.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.ItemMedias.Add(this);
                    this._ItemID = value.ID;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._ItemID = default(int);
                }
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Item");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public partial class YouTubeVideo : ItemMedia
{

    private string _YouTubeVideoID;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnYouTubeVideoIDChanging(string value);
partial void OnYouTubeVideoIDChanged();
#endregion

    public YouTubeVideo()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_YouTubeVideoID", DbType="NVarChar(15)")]
    public string YouTubeVideoID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._YouTubeVideoID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._YouTubeVideoID != value))
            {
                this.OnYouTubeVideoIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._YouTubeVideoID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("YouTubeVideoID");
                this.OnYouTubeVideoIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

public partial class Image : ItemMedia
{

    private string _ImageName;

    private string _ImageData;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnImageNameChanging(string value);
partial void OnImageNameChanged();
partial void OnImageDataChanging(string value);
partial void OnImageDataChanged();
#endregion

    public Image()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ImageName", DbType="NVarChar(MAX)")]
    public string ImageName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ImageName;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ImageName != value))
            {
                this.OnImageNameChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ImageName = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ImageName");
                this.OnImageNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ImageData", DbType="NVarChar(MAX)")]
    public string ImageData
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ImageData;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ImageData != value))
            {
                this.OnImageDataChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ImageData = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ImageData");
                this.OnImageDataChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of IMediaService.cs

Comment: @Ajay added the code of IMediaService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF, and all serialization process in .NET, has some tricks involved with objects that implement multiple classes.  I believe you'd find similar a exception working with just a single object in this case.

The reason is that the `YouTubeVideo` is an `ItemMedia` item - i.e. it is valid to return a `YouTubeVideo` from your method - but if we were to call `GetType` on the item it would give a `System.Type` of `YouTubeVideo`. The types don't match, which confuses the deserialization process.

When an object is serialized in .NET the result includes the given type of the object - think of it as an instruction for the framework to rehydrate the object into the correct type - and in this case the type will be `YouTubeVideo` (as that's what `GetType` returns). Your deserialization code is expecting an `ItemMedia` type object so it's complains with an exception like the one you are seeing.

You can fix this problem using the [`KnownTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx). In this case you would want to add the attribute to the `ItemMedia` class, so that the deserializer will understand that `YouTubeVideo` is known to be an extension of that type.

```
[KnownType(typeof(YouTubeVideo))]
public partial class ItemMedia
{
```

Put this in a partial class rather than your generated code, as it's likely to be destroyed by future code generation if kept in the generated class.

Comment: Here's some more info about when to use [`KnownType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

Comment: Excellent explanation and indeed `knownType` did the trick. Thanks!